# Firebase admin: Cannot read property 'cert' of undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I'm trying to set up firebase in in my node.js server. In deploy.js I am setting up up like this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin/app');
const serviceAccount = require('../serviceAccountKey.json')

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://projectName.firebaseio.com"
});
...
```

I am getting the error:

```
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'cert' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Uporabnik\hello-world\scripts\deploy.js:9:32)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hardhat-project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.0.6",
    "ethers": "^5.6.9",
    "hardhat": "^2.9.9"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello world smart contract",
  "main": "hardhat.config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

What could be causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

Replace

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin/app');
```

with

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

You would use /app if you’re going to use modular approach